# Homosexual Jokes in Islam

Tags: halal-haram, homosexuality, friendship

A lot of my friends are good Muslims, but we joke around being gay. None of us are homosexual we are all straight, but we just say stuff like "I like men" as a joke. Is it wrong to joke like this or is it haram.

Answer (score 1):

From someone who is biromantic, you’re not in the wrong *per say,* but be warned as the story of Lot is severe.

So there’s two ways someone can take it is:

A. You’re mocking the words of Allah because homosexuality is something very serious in Islam and you’re joking about it.

B. It’s harmless, you’re not really hurting anyone and not being disrespectful.

I can’t say it’s haram, but I would be careful since it can fall under mocking the story of prophet Lot.

Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said,

> “Verily, a man might speak a word to make those around him laugh, yet
> by it he plunges farther than the star of Pleiades.” 
>  Source: Musnad Ahmad 9220

Al-Mawardi reported: Umar ibn Abdul Aziz, may Allah have mercy on him, said,

> “Beware of mockery, for it can be foolishness that produces grudges.”
> Some of the wise men said, “Indeed, mockery is a form of insult,
> unless it makes the recipient laugh.” And it is said, “Mockery is only
> named as such because it misdirects one from the truth.”
> Source: Adab al-Dunya wal-Din 1/310